# Trying to install EGit plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev, egit

### I have been trying to install Egit and Python on my Eclipse. I get the following issue.

> #### Egit - http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates
>
> #### Does not even attempt to download
>
> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>    Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.3.2.201404171909-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.3.2.201404171909-r)
>     Missing requirement: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.3.2.201404171909-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.3.2.201404171909-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
>
> #### Pydev - http://pydev.org/updates
>
> #### It starts downloading and then errors out.
>
> Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile12121234234.jar. An error occurred
>   while processing the signatures for the file :/tmp/signatureFile12121234234.jar. problems downloading the artifact: osgi.bundle.org.python.pydev.shared_ui.3.4.1.201403181715.

Comment: Which version of eclipse? Oh, I see Indigo, right?

Comment: The EGit missing requirement message is saying that a minimum of Eclipse version 3.7 is required, you are on 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Install Egit from helios repository. Repository link: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios

You can find older Egit repo's [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F). Suggest you to use latest eclipse and Egit.

As mentioned [here](http://www.pydev.org/download.html)(In Requirements section) you need atleast 3.8 version of eclipse.

Comment: I have looked on this site. eGit version 0.11.1 is listed. The install fails with the error: **requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.0.20110607-2117]' but it could not be found**. I checked and have m2e version 1.0.0.20110607-2117 installed. How would I continue to troubleshoot this?